# command prompt stuck on same line

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Sometimes (rarely) it happens that when I hit **enter** on a terminal, the command prompt doesn't go to the next line, but it gets printed again on the **same line**.

My work around is to simply close the terminal and open a new one. Is there any way to avoid this?

Steps to reproduce:

1. try to log into mongo with authentication enabled, so that you get the prompt to enter the password, like so:
   `mongo --authenticationDatabase somedb -u someuser -p`,
2. then in the password prompt that is shown, hit `ctrl+c`, voila, now everything is on same line

Comment: Is there a way to reproduce it?

Comment: I couldn't find out the cause. I last got this behaviour a few minutes ago when I tried to open `ipython` and then pressed `CTRL+C` before it could open, but now I tried again and it works. I don't know, but it's not the first time it happened.

Comment: I dare to say that your system is just slow...

Comment: @Braiam incase you are interested, this just happened for me, steps to reproduce (verified by following these thrice!): try to log into `mongo` with authentication enabled, so that you get the prompt to enter the password, like: `mongo --authenticationDatabase somedb -u someuser -p`, then in the password prompt, hit `ctrl-c`, voila, now everything is on same line

Answer (score 5):

Use the `reset` command.

See `man reset`:

> When invoked as reset, tset sets cooked and echo modes, turns off
>   cbreak and raw modes, **turns on newline translation** and resets any
>   unset special characters to their default values before doing the
>   terminal initialization described above. This is useful after a
>   program dies leaving a terminal in an abnormal state.

It's useful for lots of situations where the terminal is acting up, like if a script has turned off local echo and died before turning it back on so you can't see what you're typing at the prompt...

Answer (score 0):

The next time you have the issue type `ctrl+c` and it will end the command typed. This may help, let me know what happens.

You also want to make sure what you are typing is being input correctly; that may be why it is catching.

Comment: I typed ctrl+c when it happened... it didn't help.